# Which is a good Pattern to create model Object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my app I have to build an object of with all ReferenceData.

```
class ReferenceData{
{
        public Complex1 Prop1{ get; set; }
        public Complex2 Prop2{ get; set; }
        public Complex3 Prop3{ get; set; }
        public Complex4 Prop4{ get; set; }
}
```

Above ReferenceData might have around 30 complex properties. I would like to know best pattern/way to create the ReferenceData object which is clean.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Not sure there is a clear problem to solve here.

Comment: I only have a model class ReferenceData  right now, since this model has ~20 properties I want a cleaner way to load data into this model, like have to build Complex1,2,3... so on. and then return ReferenceData  object.

Comment: See [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Usually a property will have a name and a value so a dictionary is sometimes the cleanest method.

Comment: As a side note: make sure the properties are actual properties of the object and not properties of other objects. Chances are that it is possible to group properties in their own classes.

Comment: What do Complex1-4 classes look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good option would be to use the Builder pattern.

Here's a link to some more information on the pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern

In your case it may look something like this:

```
class ReferenceDataBuilder
{
    private Complex1 prop1;
    private Complex2 prop2;
    private Complex3 prop3;

    public ReferenceDataBuilder setProp1 (Complex1 value)
    {
        this.prop1 = value;
        return this;
    }
    public ReferenceDataBuilder setProp2 (Complex2 value)
    {
        this.prop2 = value;
        return this;
    }
    public ReferenceDataBuilder setProp3 (Complex3 value)
    {
        this.prop3 = value;
        return this;
    }

    public ReferenceData make()
    {
        return new ReferenceData(prop1, prop2, prop3);
    }
}

class ReferenceData
{
    public Complex1 Prop1{ get; }
    public Complex2 Prop2{ get; }
    public Complex3 Prop3{ get; }

    public ReferenceData(Complex1 prop1, Complex2 prop2, Complex3 prop3)
    {
        this.Prop1 = prop1;
        this.Prop2 = prop2;
        this.Prop3 = prop3;
    }
}
```

This design has some benefits over what you may already be using.  Firstly this pattern allows you to keep `ReferenceData` immutable and move all of the state of building `ReferenceData` into the builder class (which should only exist long enough to get an instance of `ReferenceData`).  Additionally now you can have cleaner validation code in the Builder to make sure properties are set correctly before an instance of `ReferenceData` is created.  You could also create builders for the `Complex1`, `Complex2`, and `Complex3` data types and use them together with the ReferenceData builder to simplify instance creation further.

You'd use the builder like this:

```
ReferenceData refdata = (new ReferenceDataBuilder())
    .setProp1((new Complex1Builder()).SomeValue("a").build())
    .setProp2((new Complex2Builder()).SomeOtherValue("b"))
    .setProp3("Some third value")
    .build();
```